# Attached Properties via Model Item

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, attached-properties

How can I set an `Attached Property` on a `Path` Object (or any object) using `ModelItem`?

Of course attached properties are not listed in the `Properties` collection of `ModelItem`, so I can't use the common syntax:

```
myModelItem.Properties["MyAttachedProperty"].ComputedValue = newValue;
```

becuase `MyAttachedProperty` doesn't belong to the collection.

How can I achieve this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished by using [PropertyIdentifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.design.model.propertyidentifier(v=vs.90).aspx).

Example for Canvas.Left property:

```
var canvasLeftIdentifier = new Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.PropertyIdentifier(typeof(System.Windows.Controls.Canvas), "Left");
myModelItem.Properties[canvasLeftIdentifier].SetValue(newValue);
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you.
How did you get this solution? I searched all the internet but never found a good documentation on how to work with model item. Can you please suggest me something that can help me to have a deepest knowledge of the topic?

Comment: Glad I could help! I believe I was in the same boat as you, couldn't find anything on the Internet. In the end I found a colleague of mine who had a solution to my problem. He couldn't remember how he found the solution, so I'm sadly not able to help you getting a deeper understanding of this topic.